# Is there anyway to replace some of the block data to add an image?

Tags: javascript

I am making a JS game which essentially involves the player catching falling types of food in their basket.

Currently I have the food abstracted as coloured falling blocks to get the base layer of the game running. But I am having difficulty in replacing some of the Block attributes with an image instead of showing coloured, square blocks.

Part of the code is from a tutorial to get me started, the source link is here:
- https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/develop-your-first-game-in-canvas-from-start-to-finish--pre-39198

Also, the same food-block problem can fix the basket image replacing the main block.

The image for the food + basket I should link as well

- https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=active&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=109tXLmaDdeQ1fAPp-GZ4AU&q=carrot+graphic&oq=carrot+&gs_l=img.3.0.0i67l2j0l2j0i67j0l5.22035.23851..26200...0.0..0.66.406.7......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......35i39.ocV_1GqpqKY&safe=active#imgrc=HlN5WnY4Ah8SLM:
- https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=active&tbm=isch&q=basket+graphic&chips=q:basket+graphic,online_chips:picnic+basket,online_chips:icon+vector&usg=AI4_-kQ272sXU1YYZzeNyiyB65Ps8k7fgg&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0pb-ZuMrgAhU_UhUIHQMRC5kQ4lYIKygB&biw=994&bih=919&dpr=1&safe=active#imgrc=9ijozvqskGZ1LM:

I am quite new to Stack Overflow and programming likewise, so I am open to feedback and recommendations that you may have.

Here is the script that I wrote to add the food image which should replace the block. This can already been seen in the HTML doc (I put temporarily).

```js
<script> 
var canvas = document.getElementById("js/FoodCatcher.js");

//Draw image for object 
<img id="SourceImage" src="carrot.jpg">
function init() {
 var image = document.getElementById('SourceImage');
 canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 context = canvas.document.getContext('2d');
 drawImage(image);
}

function drawImage(image) {
 canvas.width = image.width;
 canvas.height = image.height;
 context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}
window.addEventListener('load', init);

//Draw basket for basket object
<img id="BasketImage" src="basket.jpg">
function init(){
 var image = document.getElementById('BasketImage');
 canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 context = canvas.document.getContext('2d');
 drawImage(image);
}

function drawImage(image) {
 canvas.width = image.width;
 canvas.height = image.height;
 context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}

</script>
```

Here is a portion of the JS code that I want to modify to add the image for the block.

```js
FoodCatcher = new function()      //This defines the current object along with the game colors + initiate/call things at right time 
{
 this.colors = [               //Public color appearance
  '#f00',                   //Red color
  '#0f0',                   //Green color
  '#00f',                   //Blue Colors
 ];
 
 var basketData = [            //Private
  ['width', 60],            //pixel width of the basket   30
  ['height', 13],           //Pixel height of the basket  10
  ['xSpeed', 10],            //Horizontal movement speed   4 
  ['color', '#f00'],        //Color of basket
  ['oldColor', '#f00']      //Old color of basket, used to prevent having same color twice
 ];
 var blockData = [
  ['width', 10],            //pixel width of the basket    10
  ['height', 10],           //Pixel height of the basket   10
  ['ySpeed', 5],            //Horizontal movement speed    1
  ['color', undefined],     //Color of block               undefined
  ['strength', 30]          //Points they gain/subtract    30
 ];
```

```js
var Block = function(data) {
  Movable.call(this, data);

  this.initPosition();
  this.initColor();

}

Block.prototype = new Movable();
Block.prototype.initPosition = function() {
  // Only allow to set the position of this block once
  if (this.x !== undefined || this.y !== undefined)
    return;

  // By picking a rounded number between 0 and the canvas.width substracted by the block its width, we have a position for this block which is still inside the block its viewport
  this.x = Math.round(rand(0, canvas.width - this.width));

  // By setting the vertical position of the block to 0 substracted by the block its height, the block will look like it slides into the canvas its viewport
  this.y = 0 - this.height;
}
Block.prototype.initColor = function() {
  if (this.color !== undefined)
    return;

  this.color = FoodCatcher.colors[Math.round(rand(0, (FoodCatcher.colors.length - 1)))];
}
Block.prototype.move = function() {
  // Add the vertical speed to the block its current position to move it
  this.y += this.ySpeed;
}
```

[Question edited on Thurs 21/03 07:50am]

Comment: Please break this down into a smaller example that just focuses on just the issue in question.  I suspect you want to use context.getImageData() and context.putImageData().

Answer (score 0):

All in all I would advise you to use a framework like Pixi.js to create your game, but if you are here to learn the basics, I'm here to help you out.

I guess you want to draw images instead of simple blocks. This consists of 3 steps:

#### 1. add the data to blockData

We need to add the data of the image to the block. That can be a base64-data-url (f.e. you can use a website for this: [1](https://www.base64-image.de/)) or a link to an image.

```
var blockData = [
   ['width', 100],
   ['height', 100],
   ['imageUrl', 'dataUrlOrImageUrl']
]
```

#### 2. load the image

In the initialisation phase load the image by using an hidden image and setting the src-attribute.

```
Block.prototype.initImage = function () {
  this.image = new window.Image();
  // the onload callback will be run once the image is loaded
  // use the onload callback if you want to avoid flicker
  // this.onload = function(){alert('image loaded');}
  this.image.src = this.imageUrl;
}
```

Of course you have to call the function somewhere somehow. I don't want to go deep inside the topic of callbacks, so I didn't use the onload-callback which will result in rendering a blank image till the image is fully loaded.

#### 3. use the image

You can then draw your image like you did in your html test page.

```
Block.prototype.draw = function (context) {
   // I'm guessing the position and the context here,
   // but the first parameter should be the image, created in initImage
   context.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y);
}
```